# Magento, get all product, not only active

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

I'm using this code to get all IDs from a category.

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->setStoreId($storeid)->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcatid))->getAllIds();
```

However, this only selects products that are active in the category, and I need all product, including inactive products.

How can I modify this code to get all products?

Comment: I don't know magneto, but it looks like you either need to modify the magneto objects that you are calling or find other objects that return products that are outside the active category.

Comment: Thanks Fluffeh for kicking in that open door. If I would know what object to call I would not post the question here. Cannot find the right answers on Google or in the Magento Documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to get all products attached to a specific category, regardless of any product visibility or status limitations, would be …

```
$categoryId = 11;  //Replace with correct category id
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')  //Replace to select only the attributes required
    ->joinTable(
        'catalog/category_product',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        array(''),
        'category_id='.$categoryId ,
        'left');
```

Comment: This seems to be one of those undocumented details in Magento. Using the addCategoryFilter method causes the query to use the catalog_category_product_index table, which as you mentioned is filtered by status and visibility. That behavior makes sense on something like a product listing page on the frontend, a bit unexpected as there isn't must informing you about this "extra functionality."

Comment: That's usually the way with Magento :)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Drew. This is something I can work with!